# Django - Generate excel reports based on model fields

Tags: python, django, excel, django-queryset, multiple-tables

The application is built on **django/angular**. I want to generate a excel report based on model and it's fields selected by users. You can find search UI below. I have 4 models in django. **Coach**, **Player**,  **Participation** which have foreign key reference to **Club** (One-To-Many relationship). The individual django model will act as a select input and model fields as an options

**models.py**

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.db import models


class Club(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    estd = models.IntegerField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)



    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name


class Coach(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    fk = models.ForeignKey(Club, related_name='coaches')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % self.fname


class Player(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=42)
    fk = models.ForeignKey(Club, related_name='players')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % self.fname


class Participation(models.Model):
    league = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    startdate = models.DateTimeField()
    fk = models.ForeignKey(Club, related_name='participations')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % self.league
```

**Search UI (Select dropdown)**

```
#####       ######      #######     #############
Club        Coach       Player      Participation
#####       ######      #######     #############
name        fname       fname       league
estd        lname       lname       startdate
address     age         country
```

**Use case**

```
- User have to select at least one field from the Club dropdown. 
- User can select one or more fields from Coach, Player and Participation dropdown.
```

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control" data-ng-model="selected" data-ng-options="item.tablefield for item in coach" ng-click="addField()"></select>

<select class="form-control" data-ng-model="selected" data-ng-options="item.tablefield for item in player" ng-click="addField()"></select>

<select class="form-control" data-ng-model="selected" data-ng-options="item.tablefield for item in participation" ng-click="addField()"></select>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="report()">Generate report</button>
```

**Angular JS**

```
    $scope.club = [{

            'tablename': 'Club',
            'tablefield': 'name'
        },
        {
            'tablename': 'Coach',
            'tablefield': 'estd'
        },
        {
            'tablename': 'Coach',
            'tablefield': 'address'
        }
    ];

    $scope.coach = [{

            'tablename': 'Coach',
            'tablefield': 'fname'
        },
        {
            'tablename': 'Coach',
            'tablefield': 'lname'
        },
        {
            'tablename': 'Coach',
            'tablefield': 'age'
        }
    ];

    $scope.player = [{

            'tablename': 'Player',
            'tablefield': 'fname'
        },
        {
            'tablename': 'Player',
            'tablefield': 'lname'
        },
        {
            'tablename': 'Player',
            'tablefield': 'country'
        }
    ];

    And Similar for participation



    $scope.queryfields = [];

    // add fields
    $scope.addField = function(){

        var found = $scope.queryfields.some(function (el) {
            return el.value === $scope.selected.tablefield;
        });


        if (!found) {
            var searchkey = $scope.selected.tablename,
                searchvalue = $scope.selected.tablefield;

            $scope.queryfields.push({
                key:   searchkey,
                value: searchvalue
            })
        }
        else{
            console.log('field already exist');  
        }
    };



    // SEARCH 
    $scope.report = function() {  
        if($scope.queryfields.length > 1){
            // post search fields data 
            $http.post('/api/gamify/advancesearch/', $scope.queryfields)
                .success(function (response) {
                    $scope.queryset = response;
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log('error');
            });
        }
    };
```

The Selected fields from select inputs are sent to django views for query and result concatenation.
The data send to django views looks like this

```
[{u'value': u'name', u'key': u'Club'}, {u'value': u'fname', u'key': u'Coach'}, {u'value': u'lname', u'key': u'Coach'}, {u'value': u'fname', u'key': u'Player'},  {u'value': u'league', u'key': u'Participation'}]
```

**Views**

```
def report(request):
    qfields = json.loads(request.body)

    print query
    """ [{u'value': u'name', u'key': u'Club'}, {u'value': u'fname', u'key': u'Coach'}, {u'value': u'lname', u'key': u'Coach'}, {u'value': u'fname', u'key': u'Player'},  {u'value': u'league', u'key': u'Participation'}]"""

    # TO-DO
    # Get all records of Club (field: name)
    # Get all records of Coach (fields: fname, lname) which is reference of Club.
    # Get all records of Player (field: fname) which is reference of Club.
    # Get all records of Participation (field: league) which is reference of club.
    # Export to excel
    # Response json object

    records = Player.objects.order_by('id').values('id', *qfields)

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(list(records)))
```

This is how json response must look like. The JSON response will be converted to excel file

```
{  
    "datarow1":{  
        "Club":[  
            {  
                "club.name":"FC Bar"
            },
            {  
                "coach":{  
                    "coach.fname":[  
                        "Hari",
                        "Shyam",
                        "Parbe"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {  
                "player":[  
                    {  
                        "player.fname":[  
                            "King",
                            "Leo",
                            "Singh"
                        ]
                    },
                    {  
                        "player.lname":[  
                            "Dev",
                            "Fin"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {  
                "participation":[  
                    {  
                        "participation.league":[  
                            "la liga",
                            "UEFA"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }, 
    "datarow2":{  
        "Club":[  
            {  
                "club.name":"FC TU"
            },
            {  
                "coach":{  
                    "coach.fname":[  
                        "Xavi",
                        "Hola",
                        "Them"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {  
                "player":[  
                    {  
                        "player.fname":[  
                            "Sab",
                            "Hi",
                            "Suz"
                        ]
                    },
                    {  
                        "player.lname":[  
                            "Messi",
                            "Aura"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {  
                "participation":[  
                    {  
                        "participation.league":[  
                            "Italian",
                            "Premier"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }, 

}
```

**Help**

**How i can get all records of Clubs and foreign key data (Coach, Player, Participation) related it** based on **selected model fields**?
Example of report is shown above.

Any help and feedback's are appreciated.

Comment: Add the code of your models. Otherwise it is not possible to provide you with a concrete answer.

Comment: `models` code has been added!

Comment: In your example output, players of the same club can have different coachers but this is not reflected in your models. You would have to add a ForeignKey to Coacher in your Player model for that.

Comment: @Risadinha Players and coaches are not related in this case! I just want to get all records of `Club` and related `models (Coach, Player, Participation)` based on their fields. Is it clear enough?

Comment: Then fix your example. Your example result cannot be achieved with your models. You have to understand yourself what your data relations are and what you want to output.

Comment: I have updated output of the queryset in `JSON` format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not provided the code of your models.

In general, you can get a list of certain fields using the very helpful methods `.values()` or `.values_list()` of the `QueryManager`. You can reference relation of values with `__` like `club__name`.

I suppose that one line in your export refers to one player. So, you would have to have the relation established starting at the player model.

Example:

```
Player.objects.order_by('lname').values('lname', 'coach__fname', 'coach__lname', 'club__name', 'club__league')
```

ManyToMany fields are more difficult. They might require aggregation or `extra` and `select` calls on the QueryManager.

Comment: `Export to excel line` you mean?

Comment: I am getting duplicate data using select related approach! Is there any fix?

Comment: `distinct()` on the queryset might help. You should understand why you are getting duplicates - that way you can decide whether `distinct` is indeed the right approach or whether the query is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

In fact there is a utility that allow you to export csv data from Django querysets with all its features from chaining to lookups fields: [django-queryset-csv](https://github.com/azavea/django-queryset-csv).

**usage exapmle:**

```
from djqscsv import render_to_csv_response

def csv_view(request):
  qs = Player.objects.order_by('lname').values('lname', 'coach__fname', 'coach__lname', 'club__name', 'club__league')
  return render_to_csv_response(qs)
```

Check [azavea blog](http://www.azavea.com/blogs/labs/2014/03/exporting-django-querysets-to-csv/) for more usage samples. I hope you could find this helpful.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `django-queryset-csv`.

Comment: I am getting duplicate data using select related approach! Is there any fix?

Comment: Can you share what did you try and more details about the issue?

Comment: `records = Player.objects.order_by('id').values('id', *qfields)`. When i make query like this then i see some duplication in data.

Comment: the duplication is in `records` or in the csv data ?

Comment: Duplication in **both**!

Comment: If you have duplicated `records` you have to check your database data, because the queryset will just returns you what exists in your database. If you think of making result distinct relatively to a specific fields check [distinct doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)

Comment: Duplication is not in database level rather in the queryset!

Comment: How is it possible? The queryset could not duplicate result, it just returns data matching the query.

Comment: Well i am wondering the same! I see duplication only when `values` fields are from more then 2 models. From the distinct doc - Similarly, if you use a values() query to restrict the columns selected, the columns used in any order_by() (or default model ordering) will still be involved and may affect uniqueness of the results.

Comment: Ah okay in this case, it may be possible. So try just to remove duplicates before rendering the response, a possible way is to use [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-set) to remove duplicates in a list: `list(set(records))`

Comment: records is a Queryset! `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`

Comment: Because you need to serialize it before applying set. It a whole new question.
Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111721/discussion-between-dhiatn-and-mysticcode).

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
def report(request):
    query = json.loads(request.body)

    print query
    """ [{u'value': u'name', u'key': u'Club'}, {u'value': u'fname', u'key': u'Coach'}, {u'value': u'lname', u'key': u'Coach'}, {u'value': u'fname', u'key': u'Player'},  {u'value': u'league', u'key': u'Participation'}]"""

    clubs = Club.objects.all()
    result = {}
    for index, club in enumerate(clubs):
        coach_fname = club.coach_set.all().values_list('fname', flat=True)
        player_fname = club.player_set.all().values_list('fname', flat=True)
        player_lname = club.player_set.all().values_list('lname', flat=True)
        participation_leage = club.participation_set.all().values_list('league')

        out_put = []
        club_details = {"club.name": club.name }
        coach_details = {"coach":{"coach.fname": list(coach_fname) }}
        player_details = { "player":[ {  "player.fname": list(player_fname)},{  "player.lname": list(player_lname)}]}
        participation_details = { "participation":[ {  "participation.league": list(participation_leage)}]}

        out_put.append(club_details)
        out_put.append(coach_details)
        out_put.append(player_details)
        out_put.append(participation_details)

        result.update({ ['datarow{}'.format(index)]['Club']: out_put})


    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result))
```

Comment: Thanks @Anoop! `AttributeError: club object has no attribute coach_set.all()`. NOTE: The model fields provided in the example is just one use case. **Model fields** varies according to what users have selected in the front-end. Looks like we're pretty close!

Comment: I fixed `AttributeError: club object has no attribute coach_set.all()`  error!

Comment: Instead of `club.coach_set.all()` i used select related key. So `club.coaches.all()`.